# File not found 'Flutter/Flutter.h' Fatal Error Flutter 2.5.1

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I recently got a new M1 Mac and updated both the flutter version (to Flutter v2.5.1) and Xcode version (to Xcode 13.0) (Not a wise decision). I tried running on the iOS simulator and got stuck at the error 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found'. I have updated all my dependencies to the latest version. I tried deleting 'iOS' folder and doing flutter create, but this brought me back to the same error again. I tried all of the recommended solutions from previous posts on the same issue to no avail (ie. removing Flutter.podspec, removing pod file.lock). I also didn't switch from master branch to stable (I was always in stable). I have tried almost all the solutions, but none of them have fixed it for me. Thank you for the help.

(Side Note: I tried running on Android emulator and everything works fine except for GoogleSignIn)

```
ravipenikelapati@Ravis-MBP Creww-App % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.5.1 at /Users/ravipenikelapati/FlutterDev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ffb2ecea52 (11 days ago), 2021-09-17 15:26:33 -0400
    • Engine revision b3af521a05
    • Dart version 2.14.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/ravipenikelapati/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/ravipenikelapati/Downloads/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A233
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google
    Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Users/ravipenikelapati/Downloads/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • 21F1617B-4715-4EC9-B15D-2DD55519E7D3 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Flutter error output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            8.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:92375C2D-F6DE-4B7F-869B-FD16EE37BC0A, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:64D26107-BE18-4ED7-9238-4BF3DADA2301, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BA3609E7-7F27-4440-879C-3DC65D18E838, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FE7AADF2-E380-4139-B1AF-004029F33C29, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8FA3DEC3-3F12-47E3-8490-A4E4786A8C77, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8DE0D105-9E50-4DA6-BD87-DA381C590E8A, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:89DA58EA-E4AA-4BD2-948B-76C6F7613CE6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3FB087A2-4DEA-4972-A5C0-6B74CB4B3D4C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:34C05C4F-ABF4-4D2C-8CFB-AB9D9F81496A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5EDE7A3-B3FA-4864-ACC3-E7FA1F8C689B, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:ED158108-0E9A-4AD4-BA76-14FB4B62AC5A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB6EEF02-9DBC-4F5D-8FD5-679169A0EFA7, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E122CD45-51EF-45FE-8B51-D5798606BF7A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7415DE00-6657-4F0F-BB38-8EC58323F6FF, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5487FAA8-0B72-4477-AD3F-F3F8DB3DDD04, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:21F1617B-4715-4EC9-B15D-2DD55519E7D3, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D3BA25C2-DEE0-4E5E-BFA5-B5C3708809E3, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:089C91CB-D751-4AE0-9448-2FCAB72C7A12, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F1A4CE57-775E-4753-98EB-EDBFF71FCE8C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C20EA51A-A417-4464-BD51-CD58F0C012E3, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:36BC4107-F7CA-4BA7-ADF7-60D2DD0F0E89, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-001A28A41E53001E }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from /Users/ravipenikelapati/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.12/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/ravipenikelapati/FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.12/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
    #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I have not found a solution yet either, none of the previous solutions has worked for me

Comment: I am struggling with same issue, app is working for andriod but not for IOS.
Have you found any solution because i have tried everything and trying things from the last 9 hours

Comment: Have you solved it? having same issue on m1

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because it can't find flutter.h (the generated header file for iOS).

Try running `pod install` after cleaning the project with `flutter clean`

Comment: I've tried this multiple times & I'm still getting a similar issue to above.

Comment: I've tried this solution but this did not fix it for me

Comment: I think you've to go for `flutter create .` command to recreate the generated files in the existing project

Comment: I’ve tried that route as well by deleting the ios folder and calling flutter create . In the root directory. That didn’t fix it

Comment: @RaviPenikelapati Can you please check and verify the new answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Posting as another answer as this seems possible answer and help others to see*

This should quite work:

1. cd into ios directory (`cd ios`)
2. `pod deintegrate`
3. `rm Flutter/Flutter.podspec`
4. `rm podfile.lock`
5. `flutter clean`
6. `flutter run`

Comment: Have tried this as well, still saying Fatal Error:  File not found 'Flutter/Flutter.h'

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

In Podfile:
Replace

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
   end
  end
 end
```

By

```
post_install do |installer| 
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) 
  end 
end
```

Then open iOS file in Xcode, and in Pods, for each Target, in Build Settings, set deployment target to 11 (maybe 9 is enough)

Comment: not working for m1